# Rectangle box with no top with surface area 16$m^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Problems says:

> A rectangular box with no top is to have a surface area of 16 square
>   meters. Find the dimensions that maximize the volume.

In usual case, this problem is about Lagrange multipliers. So, as in this [solution for problem 7](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~hhaosu/Teaching/0505SCalcIII/20050713-202_Midterm_1_Sol.pdf), most people find the 'dimensions' $x,y$ and $z$. But my TA says:

> Find the dimension of space where the rectangular box embedded using arithmetic-geometric inequality.

Let $n$ be the dimension of that space.

If $n=2$, then the box has 'dimensions' $x_1$ as height and $x_2$ as length of the base line with $2x_1+x_2=16$

If $n=3$, then the 'box' has dimensions $x_1 , x_2$ and $x_3$ as usual interpretation of 'dimension' in this problem with $2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+x_3x_1=16$.

And this is my solution:

So, in $n$-dimensional space, the volume of the box is $$2x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}+2x_2x_3\cdots x_n+\cdots+x_nx_1\cdots x_{n-2}=16$$Let $2x_{n-1}=x^{\prime}_{n-1}$. Then $$x_1x_2\cdots x^{\prime}_{n-1}+x_2x_3\cdots x^{\prime}_{n-1}x_n+\cdots x_nx_1\cdots x_{n-2}=16$$
Using Arithmetic-Geometric inequality, we get $$16\geq n ( {x_1^{n-1}\cdots x^{\prime n}_{n-1} x^{n-1}_n})^{\frac {1}{n}}$$ Hence, $$\frac{1}{2} (\frac{16}{n})^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\geq x_1\cdots x_{n-1}x_n$$

And I'm stuck here.

Comment: Why $x_{n-1}$ appears twice in the last expression?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry for typo. I fixed it

Comment: It should be $x_{n-1}'$. Then you already have an upper bound for the (hyper-)volume that is attained at $x_1=\ldots=x_{n-1}'=x_n$.

Comment: See LHS of the last formula. I divide left term by 2

Comment: And so? The (hyper-)volume still is $x_1 x_2\cdots x_n = 2 x_1 \cdot x_{n-1}' x_n$.

Comment: So, what I want to find is for which $n\in \mathbb N$, the volume is maximized.

Comment: Then study the LHS as a function of $n$. Hint: it is a decreasing function.

Comment: Ah!. If i differentiate as $x$ with $x\geq 2$, it's derivative is negative on $x\geq 2$. So, it is maximum at $n=2$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is :) $\phantom{}$